# The elementary particles uniformity and its limits in the context of matter

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, symmetry

We know that matter particles are uniform, i.e. they are absolutely identical ([1](https://www.quora.com/Are-fundamental-particles-of-the-same-type-all-identical-to-each-other-If-so-to-what-precision-and-why-should-that-be-the-case), [2](https://www.quora.com/Are-subatomic-particles-identical), [3](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/does-exchange-of-identical-particles-lead-to-new-state.828254/)). Particles of various properties are uniform. But if we look at bigger matter elements, when and how does the uniformity decline? For example, are molecules of a single substance also uniform in that sense? Does it depend on the scale of a molecule? What if we go for even bigger macroscopic objects - what happens to the uniformity? What about huge molecules like DNA? Viruses? Cell organisms? Multicell?

How can we describe the loss(or transformation?) of the uniformity while increasing the scale? Is there any law?

Comment: So basically your question is "Why do bulk properties differ from the constituent properties?" which is kinda tough & probably lengthy.

Comment: @KyleKanos Isn't that a valid question?

Comment: Sure it's a valid question, but it seems that the community felt that the answer would be too long to be answered here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with what are identical to each other are the elementary particles of the [standard model.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) of particle physics. When complex composites of these particles are built this complete identity starts differentiating. In interacting with each other quantum numbers enter and energy states. One proton may be indistinguishable from another proton , but a hydrogen atom might have the electron in a different energy level state than another hydrogen atom, and there groups turn up. In complicated molecules conservation of quantum numbers becomes more elaborate, for example [helices in molecules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helix). When one reaches the size of  DNA molecules, the sequencing etc distinguish them into many more groups.

As long as one can find quantum mechanical solutions/descriptions at a molecular level what happens with complexity is more and more groupings, but within each group the molecules are identical.

One has to go to the [decoherence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_decoherence)

> In quantum mechanics, quantum decoherence is the loss of coherence or ordering of the phase angles between the components of a system in a quantum superposition. One consequence of this dephasing is classical or probabilistically additive behavior. Decoherence occurs when a system interacts with its environment in a thermodynamically irreversible way. This prevents different elements in the quantum superposition of the total system's wavefunction from interfering with each other.

The quantum mechanical phase space turns into the classical phase space in order to have unique identifying sequences/patterns like thumbprints and irises. The **law** then is **decoherence**, where the quantum mechanical bricks making up bulk matter cannot be described with a wavefunction and its phases,  but with other bulk identifiers of aggregate matter.  Bulk matter is a metalevel on the quantum mechanical substructure.

An analogy is a painting. If one goes to the molecular level, the same color molecules are interchangeable. The pattern that appears by the combination of all the colors is unique to the painting. The pattern is a metalevel dependent on the molecular structure.

Comment: A wonderful answer, thank you! Indeed, calling this "decoherence" is a very deep look at the nature of things. This insight is really helpful. Now I'll be wondering if it is possible to quantize/measure/formalize it.

Comment: There exists a new field of  studies called complexity which goes a long way on these lines. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexity